# Check valid SignalR connection using IHubContext from a Hosted Service

Tags: javascript, c#, signalr, asp.net-core-3.1, asp.net-core-signalr

I have a hosted service sending messages to the client via SignalR and the client is picking them up and displaying on a razor page. Here is the stripped down version.

This works well except that the `.js` file is called AFTER the hosted service is instantiated which means the connection is not established in time for the first messages so these are lost.

Is there a way to check the connection using `IHubContext` before I send anything? Or do I need a more fundamental change to the whole approach?

Javascript (linked to the Index page)

```
"use strict";

var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("/logHub").build();
connection.start()

connection.on("ReceiveLogNotification", function (msg) {
    console.log("JS: " + msg);
});
```

Hub class

```
public class LogHub : Hub
{
}
```

Hosted Service

```
public class MsgGenerator : IHostedService
{
    private Random _random;
    private Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger _logger;
    private Timer? _timer;
    private readonly IHubContext<LogHub> _hubContext;

    public LogGenerator(ILogger<LogGenerator> logger, 
                        IHubContext<LogHub> hubContext)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _random = new Random();
        _timer = null;
        _hubContext = hubContext;
    }

    public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        ScheduleNextMessage();
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private void ScheduleNextMessage()
    {
        var nextTime = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(_random.Next(1000));
        _timer = new Timer((state) => { GenerateMessage(); }, null, nextTime, TimeSpan.Zero);
    }

    private async void GenerateMessage()
    {
        await _hubContext.Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveLogNotification", "test message");
        ScheduleNextMessage();
    }
```

Comment: Or is there a way to force the loading of the index page (hence the `.js` file will run) before the hosted service runs?

Comment: Answered here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63717414/asp-net-core-3-1-from-a-hosted-service-check-if-client-index-page-is-loaded/63718461#63718461