# ASP.NET Core 3.1 - From a Hosted Service, check if client (Index) page is loaded

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-3.1

I have a simple 1-page web app using the VS2019 Razor Pages template. The hosted service will send data to the page via SignalR. Is it possible to check if the client page (Index page) is loaded because if not then the hosted service will pause sending data? When running from VS2019 the page of course opens automatically but running from "dotnet run" I need to know if the user has loaded the page into the browser e.g. they might shut it down after the service has started.

```
namespace TestProject
{
    public class TestService : IHostedService
    {
        public TestService(ILogger<TestService> logger)
        {
        }

        public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            // HERE - check if index page is loaded - how??

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement simple SignalR connection counter

```
public class SignalRConnectionList
{
    private readonly object _sync = new object();
    private readonly List<string> _items = new List<string>();

    public void Remove(string connectionId)
    {
        lock (_sync)
        {
            _items.Remove(connectionId);
        }
    }

    public void Add(string connectionId)
    {
        lock (_sync)
        {
            _items.Add(connectionId);
        }
    }

    public int Count
    {
        get
        {
            lock (_sync)
            {
                return _items.Count;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In ConfigureServices of Startup class add SignalRConnectionList as singleton

```
services.AddSingleton<SignalRConnectionList>();
```

Override OnConnectedAsync and OnDisconnectedAsync methods in Hub class

```
public class ChatHub: Hub
{
    public ChatHub(SignalRConnectionList connectionList)
    {
        ConnectionList = connectionList;
    }

    private SignalRConnectionList ConnectionList { get; }

    public override Task OnConnectedAsync()
    {
        ConnectionList.Add(Context.ConnectionId);
        return base.OnConnectedAsync();
    }

    public override Task OnDisconnectedAsync(Exception exception)
    {
        ConnectionList.Remove(Context.ConnectionId);
        return base.OnDisconnectedAsync(exception);
    }
```

Now in IHostedService you can use connection counter implemented above

```
public class SimpleService : BackgroundService
{
    public SimpleService(
        ILogger<SimpleService> logger,
        IHubContext<ChatHub> hubContext,
        SignalRConnectionList connectionList)
    {
        Logger = logger;
        HubContext = hubContext;
        ConnectionList = connectionList;
    }

    private SignalRConnectionList ConnectionList { get; }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            await Task.Delay(1000, cancellationToken);
            if (ConnectionList.Count > 0)
            {
                await HubContext.Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", "system", "ping " + DateTime.Now, cancellationToken);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: this is awesome.. thank you! But not quite working yet. In `LogHub`, `ConnectionList` is not instantiated so `ConnectionList.Add()` fails at runtime. I tried `private SignalRConnectionList ConnectionList { get; } = new SignalRConnectionList();` instead but then the one loaded into the background service seems to be a different instance i.e. the counter is not set. Any ideas?

Comment: Dmitry - In the meantime, I made all the members of `SignalRConnectionList` static and that gives me what I need. Appreciate your thoughts on that. Thanks!

Comment: @TokyoD you must instantiate  SignalRConnectionList using DI and assign to ConnectionList in constructor of Hub class

Comment: got it. Works perfectly. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

In general you cannot answer the question *check if index page is loaded* in a web server. The server just serves content to clients that can do whatever they like with that content without the server being informed about the details.

However, if you have a SignalR connection from the client to the server you have state on the server for each connection. I think that is what you need to use to solve your problem.

You can override the `OnConnectedAsync` and `OnDisconnectedAsync` methods of your SignalR `Hub` to keep track of connections. This information can then be shared with your background service that uses `IHubContext` to send data to all clients (but only if there are any clients).

Comment: Thanks Martin. You are moving me in the right direction! That was my first approach [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63592367/check-valid-signalr-connection-using-ihubcontext-from-a-hosted-service] but couldn't work out how so I was gonna try a round-about way of checking for a valid client. I did the `OnConnectedAsync` override as you suggested and the method is triggered just fine. I used the Microsoft example `await Groups.AddToGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, "SignalR Users");
    await base.OnConnectedAsync();
`. The question now is how do I pick this up from `IHubContext `?

Comment: @TokyoD: SignalR is built to be used in a distributed environment and you need to configure how SignalR distributes messages among the servers. Using Redis is one option. To keep track of connections you need a similar mechanism. You might just have a single server and then you don't need a distributed solution. Instead you can create a singleton service which basically is a collection of connections. You can inject this service in your hub where it will add and remove connections and also in the background service where it can react to connections being made.